# Applying different impendance by Break field for facilities in service area network analysis?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, service-area

When I try to use my Break_Miles field to set own multi-impedance for every single facilities, it seems no effect but only use the default breaks. How can I apply my Break_Miles values to network solving?

According to http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/service-area.htm#GUID-21ADEC62-F784-4180-8D4D-547FB50621FD, I set this field as text field, the value is looks like "1 3 5" or "3 5 10", numbers divided by space means breaks value for each facilities. The Layer Properties also recognized my field as Breaks.

Any mistake I made?

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you include a screenshot of your network analyst settings.

My guess is that you haven't set your "Impedance" setting to "Miles".
The example from the link you referenced:

> Facility A has a Breaks_[Impedance] (in this case, Breaks_DriveTime) value of 3. Facility B has no value for its Breaks_DriveTime property.

Check under Layer properties > Analysis Settings > Impedance. So for you, if that value isn't Miles, then it won't know to use the values you put in Breaks_Miles and will use the default break.